# Holoviews Hovertool show extra row?

Tags: python, holoviews

I have a dataset where I want to plot make plots with 2 different variables on the X-axis (in 2 different plots), but I want to get the other value into the Hovertool

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = """,item_id,start,station,rejects
0,item1,2019-10-14 19:00:00,assembly,4.297994269340974
1,item1,2019-10-14 19:00:00,ST1,0.20546537908362442
2,item1,2019-10-14 19:00:00,ST2,0.494539460127756
3,item1,2019-10-14 19:00:00,ST3,0.6892230576441103
4,item2,2019-10-14 23:30:00,assembly,4.432249894470241
5,item2,2019-10-14 23:30:00,ST1,0.19071837253655435
6,item2,2019-10-14 23:30:00,ST2,0.7651434643995749
7,item2,2019-10-14 23:30:00,ST3,0.7748600947051227
8,item3,2019-10-15 04:00:00,assembly,3.55576079427384
9,item3,2019-10-15 04:00:00,ST1,0.37002775208140615
10,item3,2019-10-19 04:00:00,ST2,0.7195914577530177
11,item3,2019-10-19 04:00:00,ST3,0.492379835873388
12,item4,2019-10-19 10:30:00,assembly,4.02656704026567
13,item4,2019-10-19 10:30:00,ST1,0.22926219258024177
14,item4,2019-10-19 10:30:00,ST2,0.690376569037657
15,item4,2019-10-19 10:30:00,ST3,0.838745695410320"""

data_reduced = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), parse_dates=["start"], index_col=0)
```

I want to produce a graph with the `item_id` on the x-axis and with the `start` date on the x-axis. I want to track the rejects per station, and the combined of the assembly.

```
import holoviews as hv
import bokeh
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh')
bokeh.plotting.output_notebook()

def plot(data_reduced, x_axis="item_id"):
    x_label = x_axis if x_axis in {"start", "item_id"} else "item_id"
    key_dimensions = [(x_label, x_label), ("station", "station")]
    value_dimensions = [
        ("rejects", "rejects"),
        ("start", "start"),
        ("item_id", "item_id"),
        ("start", "start"),
    ]

    datatable = hv.Table(
        data_reduced, kdims=key_dimensions, vdims=value_dimensions
    )
    scatter_plot = datatable.to.scatter(x_label, ["rejects"])
    overlay = scatter_plot.overlay("station")

    tooltips = [
        ("item_id", "@item_id"),
        ("start", "@start{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M}"),
        ("station", "@station"),
        ("rejects", "@rejects"),
    ]
    hover = bokeh.models.HoverTool(
        tooltips=tooltips, formatters={"start": "datetime"}
    )

    return overlay.opts(
        opts.Scatter(
            color=hv.Cycle("Category10"),
            show_grid=True,
            padding=0.1,
            height=400,
            tools=[hover],
        ),
        opts.NdOverlay(
            legend_position="right", show_frame=False, xrotation=90
        ),
    )
```

And then I make the graphs with `plot(data_reduced, x_axis="start")` or `plot(data_reduced, x_axis="item_id")`

> ```
> plot(data_reduced, x_axis="start")
> ```

[image: data plotted with start on x-axis]

> ```
> plot(data_reduced, x_axis="item_id")
> ```
>
> [image]

How do I get the `???` filled in?

If I want to get the data from an individual line (`list(p.items())[0][1].data`), I get:

```
,item_id,start,station,rejects
1,item1,2019-10-14 19:00:00,ST1,0.2054653790836244
5,item2,2019-10-14 23:30:00,ST1,0.19071837253655435
9,item3,2019-10-15 04:00:00,ST1,0.37002775208140615
13,item4,2019-10-19 10:30:00,ST1,0.22926219258024175
```

So the data seems to be in the source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cases like this I prefer to use [hvplot](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Introduction.html) which is a library built on top of holoviews, made by the same group of developers. This really makes life I think a lot easier and creates your plot all in one go.

**1) With Hvplot you can specify extra hover columns easily with keyword hover_cols=['your_column']:**

```
# with this import you can use .hvplot() on your df and create interactive holoviews plots
import hvplot.pandas

item_plot = data_reduced.hvplot(
    kind='scatter',
    x='item_id',
    y='rejects',
    by='station',  # this creates the overlay
    hover_cols=['start'],
    padding=0.1,
)

start_plot = data_reduced.hvplot(
    kind='scatter',
    x='start',
    y='rejects',
    by='station',
    hover_cols=['item_id'],
    padding=0.1,
)
```

2) If you want a **pure Holoviews** solution, you can do:

```
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts

hv_df = hv.Dataset(
    data_reduced,
    kdims=['item_id', 'station'], 
    vdims=['rejects', 'start'],
)

hv_df.to(hv.Scatter).overlay().opts(opts.Scatter(tools=['hover']))
```

**Example plot with extra hover columns:**

[image: using hvplot to create plot overlay with extra hover columns]

Comment: The hvplot option works, the pure holoviews does not show the other item in the tooltip. Thank you very much

Comment: That could also be a version problem. You can install the latest version of holoviews with: pip install git+https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews.git